# Is there a way to know the height of a paragraph?

Tags: php

I would like to know the height of a paragraph. Is there any solution? Thanks.

Comment: if you want to know it in php then you could calculate the height BUT therefore you must know which font you are using, how big the letters are, what text you are going to show, what width your paragraph WILL have taking any css styling into concern and so son so practically no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in PHP, no. The paragraph will be rendered in the browser; a number of variables can influence the actual height: Operating System font size settings, Zoom settings, availability of fonts.... therefore, the height can be determined only in client-side JavaScript after the page has been rendered.

The jQuery framework has the convenient `.height()` that will give you the computed height of a HTML element and bridges a number of cross-browser issues one would have to take care of manually:

```
<p id="paragraph>Lorem Ipsum Dolor amet....</p>

$(document).ready(function() {
 alert("Height is "+ $("#paragraph").height() + "Pixels");    
} );
```

Comment: (Especially when you consider that a browser could be rendering things in a different font).

Comment: you could try to give the paragraph a fixed height and activate overflow. then you'd probably know the height in php.

Comment: @iTroubs true, but that's usually impractical and *might* be distorted by the browser's zoom setting (not sure about that though)

Comment: Hi! thank you for that! How can I save it to a php variable ? Fixed height it's not an option.

Comment: @Rocky you can't, because JavaScript is executed on client side after PHP has already run. You'd have to do an Ajax callback with the result to another PHP script instance, but I doubt that's what you want. What do you need this for?

Comment: @Rocky forget about php. you won't be able to do it in pure php. even if you pass it via jquery into your php what then? this height would only be the "last" height not the current if the content was changed in the meantime.

Comment: @Pekka I would like to have my post's image as tall as the paragraph if paragraph is smaller than 400px. Something like `display:table-cell;` but only if the paragraph is < 400px

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use offsetHeight or clientHeight in JavaScript.

Example
http://jsfiddle.net/nFRra/

More info
http://programming.top54u.com/post/Javascript-Get-Height-of-Div-onclick.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For a browser, Pekka's answer is correct, but it should be noted that it is possible to calculate the width/height of a given (and known) font (for inclusion in PDF's and images). That information can be readily found in the [GD library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) (there are others as well, but that one is the one I've used)